# The quickest and easiest way to draw a collection of pixels onto a surface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics

I have this method that finds all pixels of a particular colour; they will be in a single solid blob. I would like to know if there is a quick and or easy way of drawing them to a surface, e.g. structure them somehow and then just draw that structure to the image surface.

The pixels I'm trying to draw are structured:

```
public struct Pixel
{
    public Point Position { get; set; }
    public Color Colour { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe this is wrong, and someone can suggest a better structure for writing into a `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: Can you structure them in a way that creates a solid polygon? If you have a pixel cloud I don't think there are faster methods than looping and setting those pixels.

Comment: How do I set the pixels during the loop? I find no `SetPixel` method on `Canvas`. Or must I use a blank `Image`?

Comment: WPF drawing isn't based on pixels. Use a WriteableBitmap, as suggested in an answer. You may also read the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: I'm just battling to find how to write my pixels, in the struct shown above, just added, to the `WriteableBitmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to render them to the visual tree,  I suggest you to create a custom control and override the OnRender method. Here you can draw rectangles with 1 px edges. In case of large amount of points this approach has the best performance. If the result is blurred, subtract 0.5 px from the left and top, it should help.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) class provides you with the fastest way of drawing pixels but i have done no test to verify this.